# .Net Identity Set LoginPath to Https

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity

I m using Mvc 5.0 and identity 2.0 in my project.

Identity framework set loginPath protocol `http` but i have ssl and need to return `https`.
I can not change loginPath property with https.

it returns http://www.mysite/Account/Login but i need https://www.mysite/Account/Login

My Identity ConfigureAuth :

```
  public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)        
  {
      app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),                  
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(10),
                CookieName = "auth",
                SlidingExpiration = false                
            });
}
```

My index method :

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Have you got this work?

Answer (score 0):

LoginPath only indicates address where unauthorized requests will be redirected.

You need to tell the browser, you will only accept HTTPS requests.

If you want to use HTTPS only on some request the easiest way would be to decorate your action methods with RequireHttps attribute.

```
 [Authorize, RequireHttps]
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
    return View();
 }
```

Or use this attribute globally in FilterConfig.

Answer (score 0):

Add `[RequireHttps]` attribute to your `AccountController` or the `Login` action.

```
[RequireHttps]
[Authorize]
public class AccountController
{
        [RequireHttps]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {

        }

}
```